# Laravel Listener Queue var error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to queue an listener using ˜database˜, it works ok with ˜sync˜ but if i use database and send the variable trough the event it fires an error, i dont know what is happening. the error is:

```
[2018-08-20 11:33:23] local.ERROR: Undefined property: 
laravel\Events\sendSMS::$request {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 
0): Undefined property: laravel\\Events\\sendSMS::$request at 
/var/www/laravel/app/Listeners/sendSMSListener.php:30)
[stacktrace]
```

it works OK if i define the vars inside the listener instead of sending it trough event.

The listener code is:

```
public function handle(sendSMS $event)
{
    $request = $event->request;
    $recipient = $request->number;
    $message = $request->message;
    return $message; -> doesn`t matter
}
```

And the event code:

```
public function __construct($request)
{
    $this->request = $request;
}
```

Comment: `$request` is not a variable in the handle function scope

Comment: Please print and check $event

Comment: @SivaGanesh is there any way to check it without changing to sync? Because it`s working on sync.

Comment: Add `public $request;` to your event file, so defined as `public`.

Comment: @ako Exception: Serialization of &#039;Closure&#039; is not allowed in file /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Queue.php on line 128

Answer (score 0):

```
public function handle(sendSMS $event)
{
    $request = $event->request;
    $recipient = $this->request->number;
    $message = $this->request->message;
    return $message;
}
```

Comment: Same error, the error is on this line:     $request = $event->request;
 so no matter what i type below, this line throws error.

Answer (score 0):

define data member of the class for $request.

```
protected $request;
```

Comment: did you try to restart queue after changing ?

Comment: Yes, i restarted it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below code.

```
class TempClass implements ShouldQueue {
    protected $common;
    //this is main variable as you send in your code.
    public function __construct($common)
    {
        $this->common = $common;
        //this protected variable handle here
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        //use protected variable like this type
        $request = $this->common->request;
        $recipient = $this->common->number;
        $message = $this->common->message;
        return $message;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure on how it should work, but the error with it is: [2018-08-20 13:47:07] local.ERROR: Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $common ]] in class laravel\Listeners\sendSMSListener {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Contracts\\Container\\BindingResolutionException(code: 0): Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $common ]] in class laravel\\Listeners\\sendSMSListener at /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:933)

Comment: $common this variable is your queue data, you used in your queue class, means TempClass
dispatch(new \App\Jobs\TempClass($data));